# Should the number of questions per user be restricted?

Tags: discussion

Lately I have been worrying about the quality of the questions here, and it occurs to me that it might help to restrict the number of questions that a user can ask per day and per week. Some user(s) seem(s) to ask whatever goes through their head at the moment.

I should add that there are SE sites which have such restrictions. Also, it seems that I forgot to mention that I would appreciate it if you left an answer or comment if you have an opinion on this.

Comment: The only restrictions some other sites (the original trilogy plus Math) have are 50 questions per month, with six questions max per day. Are you sure the users you have in mind actually exceed these rates? Also, keep in mind that if people ask *rubbish* questions, they get downvoted and flagged and ultimately blocked from asking, either fully automatically or by a mod. If, on the other hand, you can ask ten heavily-upvoted questions per minute, more power to you.

Comment: I was not aware of the actual numbers, so that is a good point. The problem is that it is possible to generate many rather meaningless questions, which are not complete rubbish. I can take a text and ask an “Is this correct?” question for every sentence. Now what is happening here right now is not *that* bad, bad in my opinion not much better. Math.SE for example expects you to show that you have put some effort in answering a question yourself, I am missing that here. But you are right, a restriction of the numbers of question will not help unless it is much smaller than 30/month.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to control question quality than restricting the amount of questions posted. If someone posts 100 quality questions (hypothetically), what's the problem with that?  Use your mod powers and votes to get rid of bad questions.

Answer (score 2):

If there are more than 6 fine questions per day, we should be thankful. Bad questions should be closed, and people repeatedly generating bad questions should be asked what they are doing in the comments and in chat.